# C++, comparator and template

Tags: c++, templates, comparator

What is wrong in tis code?

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class GList>
struct TSet
{
    typedef std::set <unsigned int, sortIndices <T, GList> >  Type;  //Error, too many template arguments
};


template <typename T, template <typename> class GList>
class sortIndices 
{

    private:
            const GList <T> *l;

    public:
            sortIndices ( const GList <T> *l_ ) : l ( l_ ) {}

            bool operator() ( const unsigned int &i_p1, const unsigned int &i_p2 ) const
            {
                   ...
            }

};
```

Comment: What error exactly do you get?  What line is it pointing to?  What is the instantiation stack?

Comment: Umm, what *is* wrong with this code?  Does it not compile?  Does it not do what you expect?

Comment: Also, is there a declaration of `sortIndices` above its use in the definition of `TSet`?

Comment: What are you instantiating this template with?  It looks like the error might be that you're trying to instantiate the template with the wrong arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It compiles fine. All you need to do is this : define `TSet` after `sortIndices`.

See this yourself: http://www.ideone.com/VxBrh
Example that uses `::Type`  : http://www.ideone.com/uRWur

Comment: @Jeremiah: Thanks. I removed mine as well. :-)

Comment: Not compiling when you add `::Type` in `main()`.

Comment: @Pawel Zubrycki: Ohh.. that's why you downvoted it? If you know these two examples demonstrate two different things? Anyway, I've edited my post. Now see the example that uses `::Type` in main().

Comment: @Pawel Zubrycki. Hmm... then someone else gave without specifying the reason. Maybe he read your comments :P